# Android studio - items in second activity not showing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The button and two TextViews will not show up when I navigate to the second activity. They do show up in Design view.
I've looked at similar articles but cannot figure out the issue.
I'm using Java.
Thank you

Main.java

```
package com.example.cybersecgame;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
package com.example.cybersecgame;

import static com.example.cybersecgame.R.layout.activity_second;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_second);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you publish the layouts `activity_second` and `activity_main`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the use of this line

```
import static com.example.cybersecgame.R.layout.activity_second;
```

remove it,
and when setting the content make sure you use R.layout.'layout name', as R.layoout.... refers to you reading the layout file from the drawable layout folder

so it shall be like so

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this however it seems to make no difference?

Comment: is the SecondActivity declared/added in manifist file ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `setContentView(activity_second)` is wrong and `setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)` is the correct one.

Also `setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)` is not enough to load the `Button` and the `TextView`. You have to initialize them inside the `onCreate` method using `findViewById(R.id.text_view)`.

The TextView IDs in the code are an example. You should use your own IDs which are defined in layout `activity_second.xml`.

```
package com.example.cybersecgame;
import static com.example.cybersecgame.R.layout.activity_second;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

Button mButton;
TextView mTextView1, mTextView2;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        mButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
        mTextView1 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_1);
        mTextView2 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_2);

    }
}
```